# MPVolumeView not suppressing default system volume UI after showing an AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, volume

Have run into an issue where iOS' `MPVolumeView` no longer suppresses the system volume UI when the device's volume up/down buttons are pressed. My understanding is that the presence of an `MPVolumeView` on the screen should suppress iOS' default volume UI, but it doesn't in this instance.

Everything works as expected on load of the app, but after presenting and dismissing an `AVPlayerViewController`, the default system volume UI starts appearing in addition to the `MPVolumeView`'s UI.

There is a small sample app reproing the issue here: https://github.com/richard-viney/ios-volume-view-bug.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why does it work like this, but you can fix your bug with the following code:

```
private lazy var volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: volumeContainer.bounds)
private var notificationObserver: AnyObject?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create MPVolumeView in the volume container
    debugPrint("Creating AVPlayerViewController")
    volumeContainer.addSubview(volumeView)
    volumeContainer.backgroundColor = .clear
    
    // store notification object to prevent release
    notificationObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        forName: .AVRouteDetectorMultipleRoutesDetectedDidChange,
        object: nil,
        queue: .main)
    { [weak self] notification in
        (notification.object as? AVRouteDetector)
            .map { self?.handleRouteDetectorChange(detector: $0) }
    }
}

func handleRouteDetectorChange(detector: AVRouteDetector) {
    if detector.multipleRoutesDetected {
        volumeView.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        volumeContainer.addSubview(volumeView)
    }
}
```